# GLKit Memory Leak copywithZone

Tags: ios, memory, opengl-es, memory-leaks, glkit

Running the instruments utility against the game I'm writing shows a bunch of memory leaks related to copy with Zone when I cycle through an array and draw some simple cube objects.

Im not sure the best way to track this down as I'm new to OpenGL programming. My program is using ARC and is set to build for IOS 5. I am initializing GLKit to use OPenGl 2.0 and using the BafeEffect so I don't have to write my own shaders etc.. This shouldn't be rocket science. Im guessing that I must be not releasing something within the draw function. Below is the code to my draw function. Could you guys take a look and see if anything stands out as the problem?

One other thing to note is that I'm using 15 different textures, the cubes can be 1 of 15 different ones. I have a property set on the cube class for the texture and I set it as I create the cube in there array. But I do load all 15 when my programs view did load starts.They are small .jps files that are less than 75k each and each cube uses the same texture all the way around so shouldn't be too big of an issue.

Here is the code to my draw function:

```
- (void)draw
{
    GLKMatrix4 xRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeXRotation(rotation.x);
    GLKMatrix4 yRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeYRotation(rotation.y);
    GLKMatrix4 zRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(rotation.z);
    GLKMatrix4 scaleMatrix     = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
    GLKMatrix4 translateMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(position.x, position.y, position.z);

    GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(translateMatrix,GLKMatrix4Multiply(scaleMatrix,GLKMatrix4Multiply(zRotationMatrix, GLKMatrix4Multiply(yRotationMatrix, xRotationMatrix))));

    GLKMatrix4 viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -5, 0, 1, 0);
    effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(viewMatrix, modelMatrix);

    effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(0.125*M_TAU, 1.0, 2, 0); 
    effect.texture2d0.name = wallTexture.name;
    [effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureCoordinates);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

}
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  Did you find out anything?

Comment: Yes its an actual Apple bug. I had to burn a support call on this one. I should get it credited though. Its a problem with the prepare to draw in GLKit. I have submitted it as a bug as per Apple support. THe work around was to draw it with normal opengl es. They suggested using the opengl example and looking at who they draw thier cubes one is with gl kit other is with normal open gl..

Answer (score 2):

The prepareToDraw method of GLKBaseEffect seems to be leaking in iOS 5.1. Same leaking problem here. If I comment the prepareToDraw -> no leaking.

How to circumvent: Do not use GLKBaseEffect.